# Apache Spark 2.4 is not working with hadoop 2.8.3?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have installed Hadoop version 2.8.3 in my windows 10 environment and its working fine. Now when i try to install Apache Spark(version 2.4.0) with yarn as cluster manager and its not working. When i try to submit a spark job using spark-submit for testing , so its coming under ACCEPTED tab in YARN UI after that it fails.

I have attached the image of yarn container logs.
[image: click]

**This is  my spark-defaults.conf**

```
spark.master                        yarn
spark.driver.memory                 512m
spark.yarn.am.memory                512m
spark.executor.memory               2G
spark.executor.cores                1
spark.eventLog.enabled              true
spark.eventLog.dir                  hdfs://localhost:9000/spark-logs
spark.history.provider              org.apache.spark.deploy.history.FsHistoryProvider
spark.history.fs.logDirectory       hdfs://localhost:9000/spark-logs
spark.history.fs.update.interval    10s
spark.history.ui.port               18080
```